# asp.net mvc 3 razor & html table

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have UsersClass which will never have more then 10 items. How can I display user class with table in view something like this?

I want to show two rows with 10 cells

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, does the user class have 10 properties?  Or do you want to display 10 properties from multiple "UserClass" objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As always and in every ASP.NET MVC application I recommend using a view model which is adapted to the requirements of the view. So in this view you mentioned a table in which you want to group those users by 5 elements per row:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UsersClass> Users { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // that's your domain model => a list of UsersClass
    // could be coming from wherever you want
    var users = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Select(x => new UsersClass
    {
        Id = x
    });

    // Now let's group those users into the view model:
    // We will have 5 elements per row
    var model = users
        .Select((u, index) => new { User = u, Index = index })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 5)
        .Select(x => new MyViewModel
        {
            Key = x.Key,
            Users = x.Select(y => y.User)
        });
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally the strongly typed view is pretty trivial:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var user in item.Users)
            {
                <td>@user.Id</td>
            }

            <!-- That's just to fill the row with the remaining
                 td if we have less than 5 users. Obviously
                 depending on your requirements you could use
                 a single td with a calculated colspan or something else
            -->
            @for (int i = item.Users.Count(); i < 5; i++)
            {
                <td></td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Obviously this view could be simplified even further using display templates:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
<table>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</table>
```

and in the corresponding display template:

```
@model MyViewModel
<tr>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Users)
    @for (int i = item.Users.Count(); i < 5; i++)
    {
        <td></td>
    }
</tr>
```

and the UsersClass display template:

```
@model UsersClass
<td>@user.Id</td>
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but if it's not exact, you should be able to modify it easily:

```
@* Check to make sure your user class is not null *@
@if (Model.UserClass != null)
{
    <table>
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        <tr>
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            <td>if (Model.UserClass[(j*i)-1] != null) { Model.UserClass[(j*i)-1] }</td>
        }
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
}
```

I wrote this pretty quickly, but this should be close to what you need.